# Sort range by order of values in separate column

Tags: google-sheets

Given a Google Sheet with the following data:

*table 1*

```
  | A | B | C
1 | q | w | e
2 | a | s | d
3 | z | x | c
```

*table 2*

```
  | A
1 | a
2 | z
3 | q
```

What formula(s) can sort the rows in 'table 1' according to the stored order of values in 'table 2'?

Edit: How can this be done using a formula in only one cell?

Comment: I used both tags because the answer to this question likely applies to both Google Sheets and Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: I have removed the tag for accuracy. If that was the cause of the downvote, please consider removing or reversing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want (assuming your tables are named ranges):

`=SORT(table1,MATCH(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)),table2,0),1)`

See this example Sheet to see it working: https://goo.gl/veSFI4

Comment: I added some notes to the example sheet which should explain it

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you want to sort table 1 as a one-off, add the following in D1 and pull down, then sort on column D:-

```
=MATCH(A1,table2!A$1:A$3,0)
```

(2) If you want a table which updates dynamically, in a new sheet (say table 3) enter this in A1 and pull down:-

```
=table2!A1
```

and enter this in B1 of the new sheet and pull down and across:-

```
=INDEX(table1!B$1:B$3,MATCH($A1,table1!$A$1:$A$3,0))
```

I'm assuming there are no duplicates.